# F# use previous evaluated solution (state) while mapping

Tags: list, f#, mapping, iteration

I am evaluating an iterative algorithm in F# where the current timestep requires the solution (state) of the previous timestep. In the case of the first iteration the initial condition should be settable i.e to 0.

This would be analogous to:

```
let answer = List.map (fun x -> x + previousAnswer) 0 someData
```

What I want is similar to a fold but where the previous solution (state) is not accumulated but simply accesible.
What is the correct functional way of doing such an operation?

Thanks!

Comment: [`Seq.unfold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340363.aspx)?

Comment: [Seq.reduce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353740.aspx)?

Comment: Why is `List.map` initialized incorrectly; the signature of `List.map` is `('T -> 'U) -> 'T list -> 'U list` which expects a function, `(fun x -> x + previousAnswer)` and a starting list `'T list`, not `someData 0`?

Comment: Can you give us the signature of what you expect? I think once you do that and look at the library of functions in the List module you see if there is something there that already fits your needs, or you will have to roll your own. Is your data really a list? If not then forget the List module of functions.

Comment: Also you ask for `What I want is similar to a fold` but you use `List.map` in your example. Please ask a more thought out question.

Comment: @GuyCoder : "*Please ask a more thought out question.*" Agreed, but this can be expressed more clearly by downvoting the question. This is a _feature_ of Reddit, and one that contributers to the `f#` tag make far too little use of IMO.

Comment: @ildjarn He is new to SO; I don't think he would know what a down vote means. Also I prefer to ask the new people questions and help them make a better question that helps the community than giving them a down vote, but sadly to many new people drop a question then leave without helping those who are trying to help them. Also what do you mean by `This is a feature of Reddit, and one that contributors to the f# tag make far too little use of IMO`? I do not use Reddit.

Comment: @GuyCoder : Hah, indeed. s/Reddit/SO/

Comment: @GuyCoder, sorry my Map analogy was not clear, was purely to demonstrate the future solution was a function of the previous solution. I should have specified Pseudo code. SO Schoolboy error No.1 of many to come :)

Comment: The F# community is very helpful so please ask more questions here. I usually spend a half hour or more preparing a question before asking because IMO a question is also a way of helping the community. I typically try to include my line of reasoning, what I tried and why it failed, where I looked for info and only when I am out of ideas on what to do I ask and also make sure the question is objective. Also look at the previous answers before asking, especially for people new to F#, as the answer has probably already been posted and add relevant tags. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fold` that returns all intermediate values as a new sequence is traditionally called `scan`. And indeed, F# standard libraries do provide implementations of `scan` for all basic collections:

```
    let answers = List.scan (fun previousAnswer x -> x + previousAnswer) 0 someData
```

(also, note that in your example you have `map` arguments flipped - it should be `0 someData`, not `someData 0`)

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate my Map with additional inputs analogy was not very clear :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you consider accepting it?